# Right way to get paid from US company to India Company

Tags: united-states, taxes, india

I am a US Citizen and have moved recently to India and started my own company. My Client is in US has asked me to Fill W8-BEN form. 
I want to check will W8-BEN be applicable to my Indian company and how can I avoid double taxation .
What is right and legal way to get payed from US customers.

Answer (score 2):

If you're a US citizen - you do not fill W8-BEN, you fill W9.

If you're a US citizen - you pay your taxes in the US on your **worldwide** income. Check with an Indian tax accountant as to how to claim credit on these taxes from India.

If you're a US citizen - Indo-US tax treaty is most likely **not** applicable for you.

From the US tax perspective, you may be better off as a sole proprietor than working under your own company. However, you should check it with a properly licensed (US-licensed EA/CPA) tax adviser, and also consider Indian tax consequences.

Reporting ownership in foreign corporations is quite a burden for US citizens.